# Find the probability of the inequality.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

How could I find the probability of the following inequality?

> $min(\frac{a}{2} - |\frac{{x}_{1}+{x}_{2}}{2}|, \frac{b}{2} - |\frac{{y}_{1}+{y}_{2}}{2}|) \leq \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{{({x}_{1}+{x}_{2})}^{2} + {({y}_{1}+{y}_{2})}^{2}}$
>
> Where ${x}_{1}, {y}_{1}, {x}_{2}, {y}_{2}$ - variables; $a, b$ - constants; $|{x}_{1}|, |{x}_{2}| < a$ and $|{y}_{1}|, |{y}_{2}| < b$.
>
> ${x}_{1}$ and ${x}_{2}$ are equally likely to be any real number between $-a$ and $a$.
>
> ${y}_{1}$ and ${y}_{2}$ are equally likely to be any real number between $-b$ and $b$.

My idea is to consider four random variables ${x}_{1}, {y}_{1}, {x}_{2}, {y}_{2}$ and to notice that their probability density function is ${f}_{v}(x)=\frac{1}{l}$, where $l = 2a$ for $v$ being equal to ${x}_{1}$ and ${x}_{2}$ and $l = 2b$ for $v$ being equal to ${y}_{1}$ and ${y}_{2}$. Then to find the probability density function for the $min(\frac{a}{2} - |\frac{{x}_{1}+{x}_{2}}{2}|, \frac{b}{2} - |\frac{{y}_{1}+{y}_{2}}{2}|)$ and for the $\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{{({x}_{1}+{x}_{2})}^{2} + {({y}_{1}+{y}_{2})}^{2}}$. This will give me an expression which will be dependent only from $a$ and $b$. And I will be able to easily compute the probability for such an expression.

But inferring the expression is very tough for me, so are there any easier ways to find the desired probability? I am very new to the probability, so do not judge my question very much, please.

Comment: Are $x_1,\ x_2,\ y_1,\ y_2$ independent random variables?

Comment: Yes, they are independent.

Comment: I don't know how far you will get, but you could simplify by getting the disribution functions for $x=|\frac{x_1+x_2}{2}|\ and\ y=|\frac{y_1+y_2}{2}|$

Comment: @herbsteinberg, how could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The density function for the $x_1+x_2$ is given by a straight line of two segments, each starting at 0 at -a and a respectively, and meeting at a peak at 0.  To get the density fuction for x, flip the left hand piece over to get one straight line, peak at 0 and 0 at a.  The height of the peak is defined by the need for the integral to be 1.  Similarly for y.

Comment: Thank you, but it does not help me to figure out the problem. It just helps.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a quick answer.  You need to get the distribution function of the horible expression.